# Create the Lambda function that calls CloudWatch GetMetricWidgetImage

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to cloudwatch. I am not sure how to call cloudwatch getmetricwidgetimage using lambda function.

I have the cloudwatch dashboard and below is the json code

```
{
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "metrics": [
        [ "AWS/EC2", "CPUUtilization", "InstanceId", "i-0dc4dbaa040bcef2b" ]
    ],
    "width": 1286,
    "height": 207,
    "start": "-PT3H",
    "end": "P0D"
}
```

How do i integrate this with lambda function and get the graph?

Comment: Here are the docs for the API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricWidgetImage.html Which part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @DejanPeretin but how do i include this in azure function?